# Outputting sapply repeated (looping?) regression results to data frame

Tags: r, function, regression

I have been researching this questions significantly but I think I am at the end of my R knowledge, so I'm not even sure what to google now.

I have a set of data that looks like this, although the actual dataset will be much larger:

```
0     treatment  suva        stddev       heather  sedge sphagnum
1     burnt      12.880545   6.12E-02     0.1500 0.5250   0.0000
2     m          7.098873    2.69E-02     0.2275 0.0000   0.0000
3     sp         8.660688    4.04E-02     0.4250 0.2500   0.0000
4     br         7.734547    2.16E-02     0.2250 0.3875   0.0000
5     brsp       16.706960   0.103626684  0.1500 0.0750   0.0000
```

I want to do a regression of all of the columns against all of the other columns (essentially, all vegetation types against all water quality parameters).

Obviously, I can do this all one by one but that is hundreds of regressions, so I've been using:

```
data.table <- lapply( data1[,-1], function(x) summary(lm(data1$suva ~ x)) )
L <- data.table
L$heather
```

Which allows me to at least run regressions for suva vs. all the other columns and then examine them individually (some of them, being factors, will be junk but I have just ignored those results rather then working around it...)

Ideally I would like to run all the columns against all the columns in the dataset, and then output this into a table, but I am not sure what I now need to do - use cbind, so that the results are not printed bbut binded to columns instead?

Comment: I am not sure I get it completely, but are you trying to analyse whether there are statistical differences between your treatments between different substrates? If so, I suggest you convert your data from wide to long (use `gather()` from the package `dplyr`). This will create one column with your substrate types and another with the value. Then you can run a linear model with treatment, substrate and their interaction: `lm(value ~ treatment * substrate)`.

Comment: Maybe look at all pairs via: `pairs(DF[-1], panel = panel.smooth)` and `cor(DF[-1])`

Comment: Also `library(corrplot); corrplot(cor(DF[-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the full `lm` function maybe just use the correlation `cor` between columns as a initial test.  The `combn` function will find all of the combinations of the column names. If you have a large number of columns this could become quite time consuming.

The below sample will also screen for just the numeric columns thus reducing the number of false tests and reducing the chance of errors.

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="suva        stddev       heather  sedge sphagnum
12.880545   6.12E-02     0.1500 0.5250   0.0000
7.098873    2.69E-02     0.2275 0.0000   0.0000
8.660688    4.04E-02     0.4250 0.2500   0.0000
7.734547    2.16E-02     0.2250 0.3875   0.0000
16.706960   0.103626684  0.1500 0.0750   0.0000")

#find column names
names<-names(df)

#find only the numeric columns
numericcols<-sapply(names, function(x){is.numeric(df[[x]])})
#define all combinations
fullgrid<-as.data.frame(t(combn(names[numericcols], 2)))    
#find correlation between columns
fullgrid$cor<-sapply(1:nrow(fullgrid), function(i){cor(df[[fullgrid[i,1]]], df[[fullgrid[i,2]]])})
```